# Unexpected behaviour with paging library

Tags: java, android, android-paging

I started to learn about the paging library, And I've a problem.

I'm able to fetch the data and show inside my recyclerView, But I've really weird beahviors.

I Put logs on `loadInitial`, `loadBefore` and `loadAfter` and the first time `loadInitial` and `loadAfter` call one after another immediatly.

When I scroll down, I log `getPage` from the response and it give me the right page number after 20 item, but I really suspect it just load **ALL** the pages for the first time, I mean, I can literly scroll 500 item without wait to load even one time.

The first problem as I said - it called `loadInitial` and `loadAfter` one after another immediatly at the first time.

second problem - when I scroll up, `loadBefore` **NEVER** triggered.

I don't sure which  code I should  share, but I suspect the problem is somewhere inside the data source, If you need more let me know in the comments

**CODE**:

```
public class MoviesDataSource extends PageKeyedDataSource<Integer, Results> {

    private static final int FIRST_PAGE = 1;


    @Override
    public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadInitialCallback<Integer, Results> callback) {
        Log.i(TAG, "loadInitial: ");

        ApiService.getAllMovies().getAllMovies(API_KEY, FIRST_PAGE).enqueue(
                new Callback<AllMovies>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<AllMovies> call, Response<AllMovies> response) {
                        if (response.body() != null) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().getPage());
                            List<Results> results = Arrays.asList(response.body().getResults());
                            callback.onResult(results, null, FIRST_PAGE + 1 );
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<AllMovies> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void loadBefore(@NonNull LoadParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadCallback<Integer, Results> callback) {
        Log.i(TAG, "loadBefore: ");
        ApiService.getAllMovies().getAllMovies(API_KEY, params.key).enqueue(
                new Callback<AllMovies>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<AllMovies> call, Response<AllMovies> response) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().getPage());
                        Integer key = (params.key > 1) ? params.key -1 : null;

                        if (response.body() != null) {
                            List<Results> results = Arrays.asList(response.body().getResults());
                            callback.onResult(results, key );
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<AllMovies> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void loadAfter(@NonNull LoadParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadCallback<Integer, Results> callback) {
        Log.i(TAG, "loadAfter: ");
        ApiService.getAllMovies().getAllMovies(API_KEY, params.key).enqueue(
                new Callback<AllMovies>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<AllMovies> call, Response<AllMovies> response) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().getPage());

                        Integer key = params.key + 1; // calculate until there is no data

                        if (response.body() != null) {
                            List<Results> results = Arrays.asList(response.body().getResults());
                            callback.onResult(results, key );
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<AllMovies> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
    @Override
        public void onChanged(PagedList<Results> results) {
            adapter.submitList(results);
        }
```

**ViewModel**

Answer (score 1):

First problem:  `loadAfter` gets called based on `PagedList.Config` prefetch distance and page size configuration.To control how and when a PagedList queries data from its DataSource, see PagedList.Config

second: you load data in one direction so `loadBefore` never gets called.

Also, you should be using synchronous retrofit calls, you can find reference here:   [network only paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging#network-only-data-arch) 
Im developing app based on same api while learning about jetpack stuff, am little ahead of you (caching db + network) :)